# Redux Design Question: Can / should very often-changed state (cursor index) be kept out of store? If so, alternatives?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My app has an insertion cursor that moves with scroll:

[image: insertion cursor]

Its position / index often changes many times per second, and ought to do so smoothly. The cursorIndex state currently resides in my App component's state, i.e.:

```js
function App(props) {
//...omitted...
  const [cursorIndex, setCursorIndex] = useState(0)
//...
}
```

If I move it to store, will the overhead of dispatching actions (assuming that I prevent unnecessary re-renders) slow down the animation of it moving between multiple items per second? I'm not sure if this kind of highly temporary state is what Redux is really designed for. Though I'm new to Redux and I'm not sure.

I'm thinking of moving it to store because when an item is added, I need to increment the index so that it ends up below the item, not above it. Is there any way that a redux action can call a component's function or anything like that?

I suppose I could make a variable in store like 'needsCursorIncrement' and then put a useEffect hook on it that increments the index, but that feels ugly. Alternately, I could simply call `setCursorIndex(currentIndex => currentIndex + 1)` every time I dispatch `addItem`, but that also feels like bad design. The best thing to do might be to move it store, I just don't know if that's inviting disaster.

Appreciate all Redux wisdom and expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Redux is not meant for that kind of high-frequency updating.  In addition, a "cursor index" sounds like it's only needed by the component that's doing that rendering, and not the rest of the app.

Per the described use case, this *may* be one of the rare situations where you might want to update component state based on props / data read from the Redux store (ie, "we had 10 items, now we have 11, update the state accordingly".  This is also the only real case where it's valid to queue a state update *while rendering* in a function component:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-getderivedstatefromprops
- https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/#render-behavior-edge-cases

So, I would move that cursor index into the lowest possible component that cares about it (like a `<DatesList />` or something), store it as component state, and update that state if necessary when relevant Redux store state changes (like the number of items).

For more details, see these sections of the Redux docs:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react#global-state-component-state-and-forms
- https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#evaluate-where-each-piece-of-state-should-live
- https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#do-i-have-to-put-all-my-state-into-redux-should-i-ever-use-reacts-setstate

Comment: Thanks! This pretty much answers my question, and I won't be moving cursorIndex into redux store. Although, because the add button (which is in the header) needs to know where the cursor is in order to add an item at that location, I don't see how I would push `cursorIndex` into `<DatesList/>` .

Comment: Mark, if the cursor index is shared by other components it could be stored in redux right? Or if you want the logic of setting it's value to be defined in the consumer of the component and not it the component itself (component indicates something happened with action but doesn't actually change anything). If there is a performance problem then that is usually because components re create jsx or re render in DOM that had state that didn't change?

Comment: The perf issues are: A) Dispatching Redux actions causes all Redux-connected components to re-run `mapState/useSelector` to see if they need to re-render; B) Poorly-written selectors will cause unrelated components to re-render much more than they need to.  So, you really want to scope state usage/updates as much as possible. See my post [A (Mostly) Complete Guide to React Rendering Behavior](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/) for an extensive look at how this all works.